# Getting the node created by a document fragment

Tags: javascript, html

If I insert a document fragment into the DOM like so:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"];

const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

for (const fruit of fruits) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = fruit;
  fragment.append(li);
}

ul.append(fragment);
```

Is there an API for getting the newly created `li` without using data attributes?

Comment: `fragment.children` before append.

Answer (score 0):

you can use index to get child node

```
ul.childNodes[0];
```

If you want to get child node by text content, you can do something like following:

```
Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll('li'))
  .find(el => el.textContent === 'Apple')
```